# Why does onAppear() execute twice when placed on elements inside a NavigationView in swiftUI? (Xcode 12.0)

Tags: navigation, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui, xcode12

`FirstView Appeared` is printed twice. Once when the view first loads and again when the NavigationLink is selected.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Text("FirstView").onAppear(perform: {print("FirstView Appeared")})
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("Goto SecondView")
                }.offset(y: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        Text("SecondView").onAppear(perform: {print("SecondView Appeared")})
    }
}
```

Running the code above in Xcode 12.0 beta on both the simulator and a personal device produce the output below when the NavigationLink is selected:

```
FirstView Appeared
FirstView Appeared
SecondView Appeared
```

Is this duplication of onAppear() expected behavior?

If so, what best practices are there to load some data when `firstview` is created and then upon return to `firstview` (since onAppear() would attempt to load some data when navigating away from `firstView`)

Comment: This is a question to Apple - https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 6):

I know i'm a little late to the party but in case any one else has the same problem, just placing the lifecycle methods outside of the `NavigationView` worked for me. I'm testing on Simulator - Xcode 12.2

```
struct fakeView1: View {
        
    func didAppear() {
        print("Appear")
    }

    func didDisappear() {
        print("Disppear")
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("FAKE VIEW")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { didAppear() }
        .onDisappear { didDisappear() }
        .navigationBarTitle("Fake View", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```