# Form and List are rendering child views twice

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

The following behaviour is kind of unexpected. I have a Form with a simple View inside like this:

```
Form {
    Text("ChildView")
        .onAppear(perform: { print("APPEAR") })
        .onDisappear(perform: { print("DISAPPEAR") })
}
```

When the form is rendered the `Text` is appearing twice and then immediately disappears. Although the Form is rendered once the output is:

```
APPEAR
DISAPPEAR
APPEAR
DISAPPEAR
APPEAR
```

The same behaviour applies to `List`. I would expect that the content of the list or form is rendered only once.

Iam using XCode 12.0GM on iOS 14.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62788298/8697793

Comment: You can always try `Form { ... }.onAppear { /* executed once only */ }`