# UITabViewController in SwiftUI has its Tab's OnAppear Being Called Twice

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently making use `UITabBarController` in SwiftUI. Here is the implementation:

```
struct MyTabView: View {

    private var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<AnyView>]

    public init( _ views: [AnyView]) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView:$0) }
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        return TabBarController(controllers: viewControllers)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

}

struct TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var controllers: [UIViewController]

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITabBarController {
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
        return tabBarController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
        var parent: TabBarController

        init(_ tabBarController: TabBarController) {
            self.parent = tabBarController
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of my SwiftUI I have the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        MyTabView([
            AnyView(Text("Moo Moo")),
            AnyView(MyPage())
        ])

        
    }
}

struct MyPage:View {

    var body:some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) { value -> AnyView in
                        print("For Each Value Called")
                    return AnyView(MyView(text: String(value)))
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct MyView:View {
 
    let text:String

    var body:some View {
        Text(text).onAppear {
            print("On Appear Called - Making Service Call for \(text)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. When running this code the `On Appear Called - Making Service Call for \(text)`, is called twice. What would cause this? My expectation is that it is only run once. Should this be occurring?
2. Is this a SwiftUI bug lurking around or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, your expectation would be correct. However, it looks like a bug.

The problem appear when having content inside `NavigationView`. If you use .onAppear() on the `NavigationView`, you will see it called only once. If you use onAppear() on the VStack, it's already twice.

This has reported in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788298/why-does-onappear-execute-twice-when-placed-on-elements-inside-a-navigationvie) thread aswell

2. From my view, this behavior is wrong. Maybe report to Apple or ask why

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can confirm that it is the NavigationView inside the TabView that is causing the problem. If I uncomment the NavigationView, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I found a solution:
add on every very first `NavigationLink` the modifier `.isDetailLink(false)`
for me it stops the double `onAppear` calls